# re-arrange a double sum over (m,n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

is it possible to use the Poisson or other sum formula to rewrite the sum

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(mn) $$

for any suitable smooth function of 2 variables $f(xy) $

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? In what context are you trying to sum this? Is there a specific function you are curious about? Details please.

Comment: Is the function absolutely summable?  To rewrite the sum we need to know if we can rearrange it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the sum converges absolutely so we can discuss rearranging it freely.

Let's think about what this sum looks like for specific $m$:

$m = 0$:
$$\dots + f(0)+f(0)+f(0)+\dots$$
$m = 1$:
$$\dots + f(-1)+f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\dots$$
$m = 2$:
$$\dots + f(-2)+f(0)+f(2)+f(4)+f(6)+\dots$$
When we add these all together, we'll get something like:
$$\dots+c_{-1}f(-1)+c_0f(0)+c_1f(1)+\dots$$
How can we determine the $c_i$?

For something like $c_1$ this will clearly be just $1$.
For $c_1$, it will be $2$, as we get one factor from $m = 1$, and one from $m = 2$.

For $c_4$, it will be $3$, as we get one factor from $m = 1$, one from $m = 2$, one from $m = 4$.

For $c_8$, it will be $4$, as we get one factor from $m = 1,2,4,8$.

So, each divisor contributes on to $c_i$, so it follows that $c_i = \sigma_0(i) = \sum_{d\mid i} 1$.  This is the [Sum of divisors function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).

So, we should be able to rewrite:
$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty f(mn) = \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \sigma_0(m)(f(m)+f(-m))+\kappa f(0)$$
Where $\kappa$ is the "number" of $f(0)$ copies.  Unfortunately, this is a very infinite quantity, so I can't provide a counting argument like above for its coefficient.